# What does おんなし mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across this in a song called FoolFor日記 by Kaho Nakamura.

A section of the song goes like this:

> 帰らんとってほしくて
> 変な顔やったかも　ねぇ　ねぇ　ねぇ　ねぇ　欲しい？
> 帰さないって言われたら　帰らへんよ
> もっかいおんなししよう

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"おんなし" is a dialect that means 同{おな}じ. This whole verse seems to be written/sung in the Kansai dialect, but おんなし seems to be used in other dialects as well.

In the lyric, she most likely meant the same as 「もう一回{いっかい}、同{おな}じことをしよう」

Sources (both from Yahoo! Japan 知恵袋):
1: [「おんなじ」のことを「おんなし」って言ってしまいます。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1267985532)
2: [「おなし」これは方言なのでしょうか。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1184363396)

Comment: それよりも・・・なんか独特で聞きにくい歌ですね（汗）

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was wondering if it possibly meant 同じ, so thank you for the clarification. And yes, she makes music unlike anything I've heard before!